# C#/Powerpoint Add-in How can I save a datagridview to the presentation?

Tags: c#, datagridview, add-in, powerpoint, msdn

So I have been working on this ppt add-in. I have been saving strings mostly using the tags hash and it has worked fine thus far; however, now I need to essentially save a 2D array to the presentation. I chose the use the datagridview component and placed it in a new form.

Once the user inputs his data and the form is ready to close I have no idea where to save the grid. I essentially would like to access it later as a 2D array of some sort (there are probably easier ways to access this data); however, first I need to save it to the presentation some how.

Does powerpoint just serialize the entire presentation object and save it entirely? In this case can I just do something like:

```
PowerPoint.Presentation preso = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
preso.myGrid = theGridViewFromTheForm;
```

Or something along those lines?

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply saved everything using Tags. I suppose you can save things in other ways that aren't so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option to save data of datagridview. 
First using serialize class
second using Datatable.
Second solution:
Serialize your datatable in text and save it into presentation or slide tag.

```
public static string TableToString(this DataTable data)
    {
        string xmlString = string.Empty;
        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            data.WriteXml(writer,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema );
            xmlString = writer.ToString();
        }
        return xmlString;
    }
```